# How do I center two canvases on top of one another?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I need to display one HTML5 canvas on top of another.  This I have already managed in the following manner:

```
<canvas id="lower" width="900" height="550" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
<canvas id="upper" width="900" height="550" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to CENTER these two canvases while keeping one on top of the other.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an outer container with `text-align:center` and `position:relative`, make an inner container with `position:relative`, put the canvases inside the inner container, remove `left:0;top:0;` on both canvases, and remove the `position:absolute` on the lower of the canvases.  And make sure in the html that the lower canvas comes before the upper canvas, like you have.

```
#container {
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}

#inner_container{
  position:relative;
}
#upper {
  z-index: 1;
}
#lower {
  position:absolute; z-index: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NW6Fx/

**Edit**: I believe the z-index property isn't needed if you do it this way.  The order is just a matter of which canvas comes first in the html and which is `position:relative`.

Answer (score 3):

Put them inside of a `<div>` with the styling:

```
div#canvasContainerId {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 900px;
}
```

- The `position: relative` causes the `absolute` positioning of the `<canvas>`es to become relative to their containing `<div>`.
- The `auto` margins, along with a fixed `width`, center the `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a breakline between them `<br/>`

or

Might try to give each of them the following css:

```
{
    margin:auto;
    clear:both;
}
```

With absolute positioning you should use top. 
For the first one, for example, put `top: 50px`. That will move the first elements 50px *away* from the top. For the second one, put `top: 100px`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everybody.  For a number of reasons, I ended up just using jQuery to calculate the center of the screen.  Then, I also used it adjust the CSS properties of the canvases, but I left the position as absolute.